Creating threaded conversations in Microsoft 365
I have EWS code (not managed API) that creates messages in Microsoft 365 folders using "CreateItem". In my XML I have various extended properties, plus the "MimeContent" property that contains the standard internet headers and message content. This works fine.
I would now like to group messages together so that they show up in M365 as conversations. I tried setting the internet header "Thread-Id" to the same value for a group of messages, but this had no effect. Is there a way I can do this using internet headers? Or is there an extended property I can set?  I have read the Microsoft documentation about conversations but it did not seem helpful, as the relevant properties are read-only.
Or is this possible to do in Graph?
EDIT: Here is how I tried to set PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC in my inbound XML:
<t:ExtendedProperty>
<t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="0x0070" PropertyType="String"/>
<t:Value>This is a dummy subject</t:Value>
</t:ExtendedProperty>


You do need to set the PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX MAPI property.

Thanks for the suggestion.  Documentation says PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX is optional.  I did try setting PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC (see original message for how).  There was no error, but seemed to be ignored, Outlook Spy shows that property set to original subject, not the one I tried to set it to.  Maybe it's read only?  Or EWS sets the property on it's own, ignoring my attempt to set?

You do need to set PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX, not PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC.

I'll give it a shot.  Since I can't make MAPI calls, I can't use ScCreateConversationIndex. Is there some documentation on the format?  OutlookSpy has this: "UnnamedByte: 1
Current FILETIME: 8/28/1602 11:24 AM (-1196163072 (0xB8B40000), 121599 (0x0001DAFF))
GUID: {EBAA68B9-56D0-46E3-8F5C-ECB5E3BE5479}" Hex value "01 01 DA FF B8 B4 B9 68 AA EB D0 56 E3 46 8F 5C EC B5 E3 BE 54 79"

The format of the property is documented - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxomsg/9e994fbb-b839-495f-84e3-2c8c02c7dd9b
